# Generating random array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I'm trying to generate a specific size random array in reactjs everytime a user hits a button. The code to generate the array is the following:

```
const generateArray = (arraySize: number): number[] => {
  return [...Array(arraySize)].map(() => ~~(1 + Math.random() * 100) );  
}
```

This code seems to work when I test it separately. I can call it how many times I want and it will still work.

However when I use this function with a simple reactjs code it will only work for the first time and then it will return a one element array all the other times the user clicks the button.

```
class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arraySize: 30,
      array: generateArray(30)
    };
  }
  
  resetArray = (size: number) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      array: generateArray(size)
    })
  }

  handleArraySizeChange = (event: any) => {
    this.setState({arraySize: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value={this.state.arraySize} onChange={this.handleArraySizeChange}/>
        <button onClick={() => this.resetArray(this.state.arraySize)}>Generate new array</button>
        {this.state.array.map( (el: any) => 
            <div >
              {el}
            </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

The only way to make this code works is to change the generateArray function like this:

```
const generateArray = (arraySize: number): number[] => {
  var array = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    array.push(~~(1 + Math.random() * 100));
  return array;
}
```

Could someone help me understand why the first generateArray function is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is event.target.value gives a string and you are passing that as a size which is supposed to be a number. To fix simply convert that into a number.

```
handleArraySizeChange = (event: any) => {
  this.setState({arraySize: Number(event.target.value)});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the above function in this URL: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bardeen-7slbh?file=/src/App.js

I console logged the array & I can see it's working as expected

Comment: Please edit the answer to include the relative parts of the code that answer the question. While it's nice to be to see it action answers shouldnt rely on external sources.

Comment: I just tried using both the generateArray functions you have given in the react code sandbox and it's working as expected.

Comment: Actually, as I said before, the function generateArray works the first time it runs, the problem is when the user changes the input range and then clicks the button. 

Check out this code sandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-satoshi-xdcxs?file=/src/App.js). The console show that the number of elements is correct, but the function doesn't generate the array properly.

Comment: Got the issue the problem is here [...Array(arraySize)]. Here arraySize variable is getting passed as String from the second time you press the Generate Array Button Instead of the Number. So instead of giving an undefined array of the arraySize it's giving an array of size one with the arraySize string in the variable. So by changing the above statement to this [...Array(Number(arraySize))]. We can pass Number to it instead of string this solves the problem I guess. Look through the consoles printed in this link https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-dawn-ymx6z?file=/src/App.js